# Socialengine php Installation error

Tags: php, installation, socialengine

I am struggling with socialengine php installation to my private server. I already have it hosted but want to develop it on my own computer. I have installed xampp, FileZilla server and client and netbeans.

I download and extract my socialengine zipped folder to into a folder within ht docs. Then I upload onto the FileZilla server. I then right click on the folder to copy the path. When I paste this into google browser I am not seeing the socialengine install wizard page where you enter your licence key.

Instead I am seeing an index page listing all the folders and other folders within ht docs directory. I have looked at many tutorials. Deleted everything and re-installed.

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the cases to debug:

1. Check mod_rewrite enabled
2. .htaccess is available in that directory.
3. Server directory index set to index.php (DirectoryIndex index.php) in .htaccess file.
4. Check permission are fine on files and folders